# open native share dialog in ionic (cordova)

Tags: ionic-framework, google-drive-api, share, native

Is it possible to open a native share dialog in Ionic cordova like the one used by Capacitor [Share plugin](https://capacitorjs.com/docs/apis/share) (which we can also see in the video course at https://youtu.be/p7f6yamZxCk?t=334)?

I'm not talking about [Social sharing](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/social-sharing) plugin, I'm searching a way to show the native dialog like the one below.

In particular I want to be able to allow users saving files to their google drive account.

[image: Share dialog]

Answer (score 3):

In ionic there is only Share plugin available to share files in different apps if you want this type of share dialog you can make plugin or customize share plugin for future use [here is documentation for plugin creation](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/10.x/guide/hybrid/plugins/) or you can add feature request in [Share plugin Github](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/SocialSharing-PhoneGap-Plugin) repository

Answer (score 1):

There isn't any direct way to use capacitor plugins in cordova.